# How do I increase database variable by 1 using put method is JS?

Tags: javascript, django

I am making a web app similar to twitter that allows users to like a post.

In order to make changes to the database, I created an API that allows one to use GET, PUT, or POST methods in order to access or make changes to the database.

I am using a Django Framework database and am using javascript to send fetch requests to the API.

My problem is that I am trying to use a put method to set the "likes" attribute of a post equal to  1 more than the previous number of likes the post had. I don't know how to do this.

Below is my javascript function that runs once a post is liked. I tried to access the number of likes a post has and set it equal to a variable. However, that is not working.

```
function likePost(postID) {
  var postLikes;
  fetch('/posts/' + postID)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(post => {
      postlikes = post.likes
    })
  fetch('/posts/' + postID, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      likes: postLikes++,
      liked: true
    })
  })
  console.log(postLikes)
}
```

For some reason, the `console.log` returns NotaNumber, meaning that postlikes is not set equal to `post.likes` and is never instantiated. Thus, "likes" is never set equal to `postLikes++` in the PUT method.

This is my Models.py file that defines the database

```
class Post(models.Model):
body = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts")
timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
likes = models.IntegerField()
liked = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def serialize(self):
    return{
        "id": self.id,
        "creator": self.creator.username,
        "body": self.body,
        "timeStamp": self.timeStamp.strftime("%b %d %Y, %I:%M %p"),
        "likes": self.likes,
        "liked": self.liked
    }
```

This is my urls.py file where the API routes are defined

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("create_post", views.create_post, name="create_post"),
path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
path("register", views.register, name="register"),
path("test", views.test, name="test"),

#API routes
path("posts/<int:post_id>", views.post, name="post"),
path("posts", views.all_posts, name="all_posts")
]
```

Comment: Not related to your question. But fetching the likes from the database and then increasing it will lead to race conditions if two persons at the same time try to increase the likes. Your request should instruct to increase the like on the post and the increase should be done with an atomic operation server side.

Comment: Your `fetch('/posts/'+postID, {  method: 'PUT',` is executed before the `postlikes = post.likes` happens.